# How should I load resources from src/main/resources in Kotlin?

Tags: maven, file, spring-boot, kotlin, jar

I'm working on a Spring Boot application written in Kotlin (using Maven), and everything works fine but after generating the jar of my application, it throws an Exception because it can't find the folder src/main/resources:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\data\circuits-arrets.json
```

I read that could be because I use File class, and it doesn't work properly after generating the jar. Here's how I read my file:

```
var line: String?
val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(FileReader(File(csvLocation)))
do {
    line = bufferedReader.readLine()
    if (line != null) {
        //Do something with 'line'
    }
} while (line != null)
```

I found some solutions using InputStream instead of File in the BufferedReader.
My question is: Does it really change something for the jar? If yes, how should I do then?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** 
Here's the output of the command `jar tvf my-jar.jar` :

```
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 META-INF/
   552 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/springframework/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/springframework/boot/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/springframework/boot/loader/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/
  2688 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/
  9736 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection.class
  1374 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$JarFileType.class
 14915 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile.class
  3414 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntry.class
   345 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/FileHeader.class
  3172 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/StringSequence.class
  4976 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AsciiBytes.class
  1593 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$1.class
  1997 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.class
 10728 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries.class
   540 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryVisitor.class
   299 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryFilter.class
  5267 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryFileHeader.class
  3116 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
  4624 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryParser.class
  1693 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/ZipInflaterInputStream.class
 11509 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Handler.class
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/
   302 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$Entry.class
   437 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$EntryFilter.class
   945 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive.class
  1487 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator$EntryComparator.class
  3837 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator.class
  5243 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive.class
  1484 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
 19737 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.class
   282 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$1.class
  2062 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$1.class
  1233 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$2.class
  3263 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.class
  4015 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile.class
  1102 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
  1081 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class
  7336 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive.class
  1502 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/MainMethodRunner.class
  3608 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/
  5203 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/SystemPropertyUtils.class
   485 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessData.class
   273 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$1.class
  1779 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.class
  1953 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
   266 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$1.class
  4684 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.class
  1721 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/WarLauncher.class
  1585 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
  1527 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.class
  5687 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
   616 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Bytes.class
   702 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$1.class
  4306 Wed May 09 13:32:20 CEST 2018 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/constants/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:33:50 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/data/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/jsonEntities/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/viewModels/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/security/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/services/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:10 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/utils/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:12 CET 2019 META-INF/maven/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:12 CET 2019 META-INF/maven/com.auth0.samples/
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:12 CET 2019 META-INF/maven/com.auth0.samples/kotlin-spring-boot/
   584 Fri Feb 15 10:33:50 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties
 87499 Fri Feb 15 10:33:50 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/data/circuits-arrets.json
261015 Fri Feb 15 10:33:50 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/data/tan-arrets.csv
  1029 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/Configuration.class
  3471 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/ApplicationUserController.class
  6013 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/BaseController.class
  1701 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/BikeStationController.class
  1692 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/BusStationController.class
   612 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/FavoriteController$WhenMappings.class
  5385 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/FavoriteController.class
  1778 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/LineController.class
  7389 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/controllers/StationController.class
  1868 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/jsonEntities/Arret.class
  1079 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/jsonEntities/BusLineLibelle.class
  3252 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/ApplicationUser.class
  2977 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/BikeStation.class
  2140 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/Favorite.class
  2981 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/Station.class
  1195 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/viewModels/BaseVM.class
  3691 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/viewModels/StationVM.class
  1663 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/KotlinSpringBootApplicationKt.class
   812 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/BaseRepository.class
   702 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/BusStationRepository.class
   672 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/LineRepository.class
  5530 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/security/JWTAuthenticationFilter.class
  2578 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/security/UserDetailsServiceImpl.class
  4617 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/services/BaseService.class
  1186 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/services/LineService.class
  5525 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/StartingDataInjector.class
  7943 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/utils/ParsersKt.class
   121 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 META-INF/kotlin-spring-boot.kotlin_module
  7216 Fri Feb 15 10:31:38 CET 2019 META-INF/maven/com.auth0.samples/kotlin-spring-boot/pom.xml
  1693 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/constants/ConstantsKt.class
  1805 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/AccessCondition.class
  1065 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/BaseEntity.class
  3506 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/BusStation.class
  1434 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/FavoriteType.class
  2945 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/Line.class
  2056 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/mainEntities/StationType.class
  2081 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/entities/viewModels/LineVM.class
   613 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/KotlinSpringBootApplication.class
  1101 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/ApplicationUserRepository.class
   707 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/BikeStationRepository.class
   692 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/FavoriteRepository.class
   687 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/repositories/StationRepository.class
  4738 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/security/JWTAuthorizationFilter.class
  6776 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/security/WebSecurity.class
  1235 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/services/BikeStationService.class
  1228 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/services/BusStationService.class
  1207 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/services/StationService.class
  2405 Fri Feb 15 10:34:06 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/utils/FindersKt.class
  5205 Fri Feb 15 10:34:08 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/fr/asi/VMUtils.class
   114 Fri Feb 15 10:34:12 CET 2019 META-INF/maven/com.auth0.samples/kotlin-spring-boot/pom.properties
 29487 Fri Feb 15 10:33:50 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/data/stations-velos-libre-service-nantes-metropole.csv
     0 Fri Feb 15 10:34:14 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/
   628 Wed May 09 13:41:28 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
   593 Wed May 09 13:30:56 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
927496 Wed May 09 13:19:02 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
1161361 Wed May 09 13:25:34 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
   613 Wed May 09 13:30:56 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
290339 Fri Mar 31 21:27:54 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
471901 Fri Mar 31 21:27:16 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
 17519 Sun Nov 19 01:08:44 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar
255485 Sun Nov 19 00:48:58 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
  4596 Thu Mar 16 17:37:48 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
 26586 Wed Feb 21 15:54:16 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
297518 Sat Oct 14 11:44:44 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.19.jar
   600 Wed May 09 13:41:20 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
1930381 Wed Nov 15 11:26:54 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar
   598 Wed May 09 13:41:22 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
143471 Thu Apr 05 17:30:38 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/HikariCP-2.7.9.jar
401279 Tue May 08 08:06:44 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
6739203 Thu Apr 26 11:06:04 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar
 66469 Wed Feb 14 13:23:28 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
113371 Fri Jul 26 12:01:34 CEST 2013 BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
739582 Tue Oct 10 18:04:58 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar
445288 Wed Sep 06 11:15:06 CEST 2006 BOOT-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
186741 Tue Aug 02 13:41:56 CEST 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
 65100 Sat Sep 09 14:47:28 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/classmate-1.3.4.jar
313898 Mon May 16 14:19:12 CEST 2005 BOOT-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
 75288 Tue Nov 24 15:03:08 CET 2015 BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
 30724 Mon May 13 15:11:34 CEST 2013 BOOT-INF/lib/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
335660 Tue May 08 14:29:02 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
1076871 Tue May 08 14:23:50 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
191789 Tue May 08 08:07:28 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
255201 Tue May 08 08:06:38 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
 41203 Thu Mar 16 17:36:32 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
 46745 Tue May 08 08:08:48 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aspects-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
   588 Wed May 09 13:41:32 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
   645 Wed May 09 13:41:30 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
 33392 Mon Mar 26 15:55:48 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.5.jar
 99630 Mon Mar 26 15:56:26 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.5.jar
  8646 Mon Mar 26 15:54:04 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.5.jar
   591 Wed May 09 13:41:32 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
3115994 Fri Apr 27 21:24:52 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar
240244 Fri Apr 27 21:24:54 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.31.jar
256776 Fri Apr 27 21:24:54 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar
1130724 Tue Mar 27 09:03:18 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar
 93107 Tue Dec 19 16:23:28 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
1254097 Tue May 08 08:07:04 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
789889 Tue May 08 08:07:52 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
   604 Wed May 09 13:41:42 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
366299 Tue May 08 08:06:20 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
691611 Tue May 08 15:25:12 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
494788 Tue May 08 15:24:48 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
 72603 Thu Jan 10 22:41:24 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-crypto-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar
433210 Thu Jan 10 22:41:26 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar
660573 Tue May 08 08:06:02 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
1090735 Tue May 08 08:06:32 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
1226584 Tue May 08 08:05:54 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
 21704 Tue May 08 08:05:42 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jcl-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
279878 Tue May 08 08:06:20 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
 13769 Tue Nov 13 13:35:54 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.10.jar
1181292 Tue Nov 13 13:25:52 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar
151024 Tue Nov 13 13:24:28 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar
 17536 Tue Dec 17 16:10:34 CET 2013 BOOT-INF/lib/annotations-13.0.jar
  3137 Tue Nov 13 13:35:52 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.10.jar
2645740 Tue Nov 13 13:33:06 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar
501860 Wed Aug 15 21:36:52 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.jar
127509 Fri Aug 04 15:17:50 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar
164361 Sun Dec 23 12:30:54 CET 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/klaxon-5.0.1.jar
 50732 Thu Jan 03 15:45:18 CET 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/java-jwt-3.5.0.jar
1342410 Mon Mar 26 15:13:56 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar
 66519 Sat Jul 29 20:53:26 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
321590 Mon Mar 26 08:04:00 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.9.5.jar
335042 Tue Oct 17 08:53:20 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar
1007502 Tue Aug 07 08:59:10 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar
```

Comment: normally whatever is there inside `src/main/resources/` is copied by the build tool (e.g., Maven) to the output folder, which won't hence contain `src/main/resources/` anymore. Example: file `src/main/resources/foo.txt` will be copied to `/foo.txt` within the generated JAR file

Comment: That's what I though but when lauching, the application is unable to find my files... I don't get why.

Comment: Use `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html or just search for the names to find examples). This isn't specific to Kotlin.

Comment: So you think my application doesn't find the resource file because I didn't use one of these function?

Comment: Why not open the output jarfile to determine the path?

Comment: If I do that, my jar will work, but the application in my IDE will not work anymore. It's not a good solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I don't if know using the BufferedReader is still the best practice, but I decided to keep it in my code as everything was done with it already. So I dropped the use of File class, and I used the following to get a resource from `src/main/resources`:

```
 var line: String?
 val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(csvLocation)))
 do {
     line = bufferedReader.readLine()
     if (line != null) {
         //Do something with 'line'
     }
 } while (line != null)
```

csvLocation value is `"data/myFile.csv"`. This file is located in `src/main/resources/data`

Finally this solution works in my IDE and in the generated jar. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The production app will not run in your IDE, right? So that is of lesser importance than finding where the file exists on the classpath.

Essentially, there is no `src/main/resources` dir in the jar file - that directory is just a Maven convention for holding resources in a project. If you crack the jar and find the files in question, you'll understand better where Maven puts those files at package time and how to access them. Also note, a Maven-aware IDE will put files in `src/main/resources` on the app classpath, so the app will likely run in the IDE as well once the correct solution is identified.

To access the `application.properties` file in the example, use `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` as suggested, with path `/BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties`. Note the first slash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, how should I do ? For now I'm searching my file with the path "src/main/resources/myFile.csv", should I change the path? It is counterintuitive to use a path which not exist yet in my IDE (but only in the jar). I guess there's another way to do it?

Comment: Yes, the jar will not include `src/main/resources`. View the jar contents with `jar tvf <theJarName>.jar` to find where myFile.csv is. Then try that path.

Comment: Please run the `jar tvf` command I provided and add the output to the question. Then specifically indicate the file you're trying to open.

Comment: I edited my question. I try to access to one of the three files in the directory `BOOT-INF/classes/data/` of my jar.